# socket.io doesn't fires event connection

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have server side

```
import io from 'socket.io';


export function startServer(store){
    const server = new io(7000);   
    store.subscribe(() => {
        server.sockets.emit("state", store.getState().toJS());
    })
    server.on('conneсtion', socket => {
        console.log(`${socket.handshake.address} has joined`)
        socket.emit("state", store.getState().toJS());
        socket.on("action", store.dispatch.bind(store));
    });
}
```

and client side

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {VotingContainer} from './components/Voting';
import {BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './components/App';
import {ResultsContainer} from './components/Results';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import reducer from './reducer';
import {fromJS} from 'immutable';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import {setState} from './actionCreators';
import remoteActionMiddleware from './remoteActionMiddleware';
import {Map, List} from 'immutable';

const socket = new io('localhost:7000');
socket.on('state', state => {
        console.log(state);
        store.dispatch(setState(state))
});
console.log(socket);

socket.on('connect', () => {
    alert('connected');

})

const createStoreWithMiddleWare = applyMiddleware(remoteActionMiddleware)
(createStore);
const store = createStoreWithMiddleWare(reducer);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Route component={App}/>       
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("root")
)
```

Firstly I start server

```
babel-node index.js
```

Then start client by means of webpack-dev-server.

Eventually event "connect" on client side fires but on server side event "connection" doesn't fires. So I cannot transfer state from server to client

What's the reason of this?

Comment: On thing you might try is changing `const socket = new io('localhost:7000');` to `const socket = io('http://localhost:7000');`.  `io()` wants a URL passed to it, not just a host name and there's no need to use `new` with it either.

Comment: Seems problem was in word 'connect', 'c' was on russion. Thanks for attention anywhere